# Which ABEC to use for park skating?

Tags: gear, skateboarding

I'm pretty new to skateboarding and I've ordered my first "real" deck. The shop mailed me which [ABEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABEC_scale) I want to have for my ball bearings.

> The ABEC scale is an industry accepted standard for the tolerances of
>   a ball bearing. It was developed by the Annular Bearing Engineering
>   Committee (ABEC) of the American Bearing Manufacturers Association
>   (ABMA).

I've half of a year experience and skating mainly in parks. They let me choose between 3, 5 (their recommendation) and 7.

What to choose?

Comment: any. for park you don't really care. in rollerskating, the usual and most common is 5, with 7 (or even 9) for speed skates, and 3 for cheaper or park skates. (obviously, 7 is better, but usually more expensive)

Comment: I started a discussion on meta about questions relating to sports which rely heavily on human made infrastructure (http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/755/sports-questions-relying-on-significant-infrastructure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until you are an amazingly skilled skater, just go with a 5. They are cheap, and to be honest, you won't be able to notice the difference. I've skated for years and I can't really tell when I'm on a board whether it's a 5 or a 7 or whatever.

Higher tolerance bearings will last longer, theoretically, and pick up less grit, but I treat bearings and wheels as consumables at a price point they just get replaced when too worn.

Comment: That's just it. Diminishing returns. My kids beats the beeguz out of his boards and bikes, buys the best stuff but destroys it within a few months. I keep telling him it's not worth it to have the best of the best if beating the beeguz out of it is what you plan to do.